# Remove Specific Namespace from XSLT

Tags: xslt, jdeveloper, bpel

Hi Need Suggestion I want to remove Particular NameSpace using xslt

**Input is Given below :-**

```
            <GNRequest 
        xmlns="http://xmlns.tom.be/cms">     
           <Input>   
              <DocumentInputs>
                 <DocumentInput>   

                    <Language>DE</Language>
                    <TemplateInput>
                        <MPC>
                        <InteractionType xmlns="asdfasd">MobileProductOptionActivation</InteractionType>
                        <SMdn>123456</SMdn>             
                        </MPC>
                        </TemplateInput>
                 </DocumentInput>        
              </DocumentInputs>
           </Input>
        </GNRequest>
```

**After Apply XSLT Output becomes:**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tns:Input xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.tom.be/csm/v001" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:jca="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/wsdl/jca/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:pc="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/" xmlns:plt="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/">
        <tns:DocumentInputs>
        <tns:DocumentInput>
        <tns:Language>DE</tns:Language>
        <tns:TemplateInput>
        <MPC xmlns="http://xmlns.tom.be/cms">
        <InteractionType 
           xmlns="asdfasd">MobileProductOptionActivation</InteractionType>
        <SMdn>123456</SMdn>             
        </MPC>
        </tns:TemplateInput>
        </tns:DocumentInput>
        </tns:DocumentInputs>
        </tns:Input>
```

**So extranameSpace added xmlns ="http://xmlns.tom.be/cms"**

**XSLT :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.tom.be/csm/v001"
                 xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.tom.be/cms"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>

   <xsl:template match="/">
     <tns:Input>
       <tns:DocumentInputs>
         <xsl:for-each 
select="/ns0:GNRequest/ns0:Input/ns0:DocumentInputs/ns0:DocumentInput">
           <tns:DocumentInput>
             <tns:Language>
               <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Language"/>
             </tns:Language>
             <tns:TemplateInput>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="(ns0:TemplateInput/*)"/></tns:TemplateInput>
           </tns:DocumentInput>
         </xsl:for-each>
       </tns:DocumentInputs>
     </tns:Input>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy >
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the XSLT you are currently using for this transformation? Thanks!

Comment: Also, is this the complete input document? Since the output is not well-formed, it looks like you cut at least one line from the output.

Comment: Which XSLT version you are using can you tell or post XSLT code as well?

Comment: Hi Add Input and Output also Xslt code can you check.I am using xslt version 2.0

Comment: Can you edit your question to ensure the XSLT is readable. It seems to be missing a large chunk at the moment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another rule to match the elements you desire and create a new element with the same local name, but without a namespace:

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<!-- the above goes before ... -->

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that in general it's not a good idea to remove namespaces, since you are losing information.

Comment: Phihag Actually it working for this input .if i add namespace like <MPC xmlns:xsi ="http:mail"> it remove extra namespace as well as xmlns:xsi ="http:mail" i want to keep my input same with namespace in output.